# Python http.client throws BadStatusLine on a perfectly valid HTTP, on 1 system only. Wireshark verified

Tags: python, http

On all my systems, the following HTTP request gives me the response below (not HTTPS, API key censored):

```
GET /ShippingAPI.dll?API=RateV4&XML=%3CRateV4Request+USERID%3D%22xxxxxxx%22%3E%0A%09%09%09%3CPackage+ID%3D%221%22%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CService%3EALL%3C%2FService%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CZipOrigination%3E71343%3C%2FZipOrigination%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CZipDestination%3E98501%3C%2FZipDestination%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CPounds%3E5%3C%2FPounds%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3COunces%3E0%3C%2FOunces%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CContainer%3EVARIABLE%3C%2FContainer%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CSize%3EREGULAR%3C%2FSize%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CWidth%3E7%3C%2FWidth%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CLength%3E7%3C%2FLength%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CHeight%3E6%3C%2FHeight%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CGirth%3E33%3C%2FGirth%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CMachinable%3Efalse%3C%2FMachinable%3E%0A%09%09%09%3C%2FPackage%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2FRateV4Request%3E HTTP/1.1
Host: production.shippingapis.com
Accept-Encoding: identity
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
X-Backside-Transport: OK OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 08 Nov 2018 21:26:14 GMT
X-Global-Transaction-ID: 0bee6b0a5be4a9f7ea895831
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 1070
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RateV4Response><Package ID="1"><ZipOrigination>713...
```

This information comes from Wireshark.

I'm running the same Python version everywhere, 3.6.1 32b, packages installed with pipenv so they are all identical.

Why does one computer choke on this line:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: I've created a python file with the code from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/http/client.py in it so that I can run that and step into the actual source to see what's going on. I know this is like blogging but I'll thank me later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot twist: it was malware. **Wireshark** showed the actual server's HTTP response, which started with **HTTP/1.1 200 OK**. However, *this is not what Python's **http.client** saw.*

I downloaded the *http.client* source from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/http/client.py, ran it, and stepped into it with a debugger. The HTTP response it was seeing, started with **HTTP/1.1 100 CONTINUE**. Wireshark showed me one thing, and http.client showed me another thing.

To log *http.client*'s data to stdout, use this, even if you use *Requests*:

```
http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
```

This symptom could only mean one thing: something's messing with my HTTP traffic between Wireshark and the application layer. I installed Malwarebytes and it found:

```
Type: Potentially Unwanted Program (PUP)
Name: PUP.Optional.Winsock.WnskRST
Path: C:\Windows\Provider.dll
```

After removing that and a bunch of other crap, and a few reboots, http.client is now happy and sees the HTTP/1.1 200 OK header like it should.